# Unable to Set DPI for png files ImageMagik

Tags: imagemagick, png, magick++

I am using ImageMagik 6.7.8 c++ library for image creations from raw images . The problem is I am not able to set DPI for the file type "png" . Whereas it works perfectly ok with jpeg,tiff . Following is the sample code

```
Magick::Image output;
Magick::Blob outputBlob;
output.read(geometry->getWidth(), geometry->getHeight(), "RGBA", Magick::CharPixel, buffer.get()); // Buffer is the raw image
output.resolutionUnits(PixelsPerInchResolution);
const Magick::Geometry gm(150,150);
output.density(gm);
// Write final
output.write(&outputBlob, "PNG");
```

If I replace PNG by JPG or TIFF in the call output.write I see the correct DPI

Comment: Pixel density is discarded by the PNG & GIF formats. This is by design in PNG as this format is a lossless raster image, and (IMHO) would not be subjected to pre-rendering methods in traditional printing. See [Myths of DPI](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2010/02/the-myth-of-dpi/) for additional info.

Comment: @emcconville: while I doubt this question is about *programming*, please make sure to make relevant comments. This question is about the inverse of the Myth that gets discussed on that page - dpi is irrelevant for web, is how I read it. Also, the `pHYs` tag is [part of the official specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#11pHYs). It may be as simple as ImageMagick not using the chunk. And that's allowed, per the same specifications. (Also, the fact that PNG is lossless is independent of this.)

Comment: @Jongware Yes, your right. I was misinformed & thinking about screen-printers. The `pHYs` tag must be opted-in during creation. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we observed is that the header did contain the DPI information when we viewed in Photoshop or IrfanView . However for unknown reasons its not visible in ms paint